# Force to not reload a uiwebview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, feed

I'm working in a news feed.

I have a uiwebview who load an url and show all the news. The problem is, that page has a button: "Load more news" at the bottom of the web page. So, when the user press there, the page load more news.

The problem happen, when we have a video in one of our news. Because, when the user press over "load more news" the uiwebview refresh the page and the scroll go back to the top of position.

So... my question is: There are a way to solve this?
Can we stop a refresh?

Thanks.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the position of the webview before the load more news button is tapped in a variable

```
CGPoint scrollOffset = self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset;
```

And you can later restore its position by setting the same scrollOffset to the webview again:

```
[self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:scrollOffset];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to handle UIWebView delegate -shouldStartRequest and return NO in your case.